# Generators in cyclic group - specific example

Tags: cyclic-groups

I need to show that $(\mathbb{Z}_4 \ (0), \times)$ with multiplication modulo 5 has 2 generators; $2$ and $4$.
I understand why $2$ is a generator, but I don't get why $4$ is.

Edit: I'm not sure that's formatting correctly but it should be the set of non-zero integers with addition modulo 4.

I figured, as it is multiplication modulo five you would do
$4^1 = 4$, $4^2=1$, $4^3 = 4$, $4^4=1$
so I fail to see how this could be a generator as I was under the impression you needed to produce all the elements.

I worked out the generator $2$ in the same way so unless it's a coincindence that I got the answer correct I don't see why it doesn't work for 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are considering the group that is often denoted $\mathbb{Z}_5^\times$. Some people don't like the $\times$ because they think of rings (and you might not know about them yet). Since it is modulo $5$, you have $4$ the same as $-1$, so $4$ is not a generator for this group. $2$ is a generator because 
$$
2^1 = 2 \\
2^2 = 4 \\
2^3 = 3 \\
2^4 = 1.
$$
So you get everything in the group. If you check, then you will find that $3$ is also a generator.

Comment: My lecturer has written in his notes that 4 is a generator, hence my confusion.

Comment: @Alice $4$ is not a generator. $3$ is a generator though.

Comment: Ah got it. Thank you for clearing up my confusion!